# Handling page breaks / sections

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm using a Google Apps Script to update dropdown menus in a Google Form, the script worked fine.  The dropdown list got so big that I had to create multiple sections in the Google Form. I'm struggling to create a code that jumps over the section breaks.

I guess the critical point is the `forEach` method in the main function:

```
labels.forEach(function(label,i)
```

I'm not sure which method I should use so that the main function updates all dropdown lists.
Is

```
FormApp.PageNavigationType.CONTINUE;
```

the right method to use?

Here is the code I've so far:

```
var ssID = "...";
var formID = "...";
var wsData = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("data");  
var form = FormApp.openById(formID);
var section = form.getGoToPage(1);

function main(){
  var labels = wsData.getRange(1,1,1,wsData.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
 

  labels.forEach(function(label,i){
      var options = wsData
                          .getRange(2,i+1,wsData.getLastRow()-1,1)
                          .getValues()
                          .map(function(o){ return o[0]})
                          .filter(function(o){ return o !==""});
      updateDropDownUsingTitle(label,options);
  });


}


function updateDropDownUsingTitle(title,values) {

  
  var items = form.getItems();
  var titles = items.map(function(item){
    return item.getTitle();


  });

  var pos = titles.indexOf(title);
  if(pos !== -1){
  var item = items[pos];
  var itemID = item.getId();
  updateDropdown(itemID,values);
  }
}

function updateDropdown(id,values) {

  var item = form.getItemById(id);
  item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm struggling to create a code that jumps over the section breaks."?

Comment: I get the following error, when I run the code: Exception: Invalid conversion for item type: PAGE_BREAK. In line 52. Because asListItem() is trying to set values to a PAGE_BREAK item. And I want to find a way to handle this exception.

Comment: You can try-catch that function, my question is what's the purpose of the dropdown list?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to filter the list of items so that it only contains your dropdown list items.

```
var items = form.getItems();
var listItems = items.filter(item=>item.getType() === 'LIST')
```